# How to split the date in 3 lines in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching around for an answer but nothing good.

I am using twenty twelve theme.What I am trying to do is changing the *post date*  from:
 **31.march.2016** to [image: this] ,I want it in 3 lines separated like in the image .

Thank you !

This is my date code:

```
$date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                esc_html( get_the_date() )
             );

<span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
```

Comment: @Anant it outputs me March 30, 2016
<span class="entry-date">March 30, 2016</span>

Comment: `<?php $data = explode(' ',get_the_date()); echo trim($data[1],',').'<br>'.$data[0].'<br>'.$data[2]; ?>`

Comment: @Anant hmm , it outputs 

March
space here 
2016

Comment: @Anant yes its working , but how can i get the current date ? :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you said that `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>` outputs:- March 30, 2016**

So do like below:-

```
<span class="entry-date"><?php $data = explode(' ',get_the_date()); echo trim($data[1],',').'<br>'.$data[0].'<br>'.$data[2]; ?></span>
```

Comment: i must have done something :)) ,i will fix it somehow , Thank you for help

Comment: Glad to help you.:):)